# Access string value from array in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

How can i get each value from the below array in smarty?
I have :

`{$categ|var_dump}`  is

```
array(16) {
  [0]=>
  string(63) "
  string(6) "MEN
  string(29) "
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(6) "
  string(97) "
  string(23) "Incaltaminte barbati
  string(29) "
  string(0) ""
  [9]=>
  string(6) "
  string(72) "
  string(10) "Pantofi
  string(29) "
  string(0) ""
  [14]=>
  string(6) "
  string(5) "PRADA"
}
```

I have tried : `{$categ[8]} ..{$categ[x]}` but its not returning nothing.

Have any ideea ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a [foreach](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) loop in Smarty?

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$myArray item=foo}
    <li>{$foo}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach to access element of array.You can use following example to learn that how to access array element.

```
$a = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "seventeen" => 17
);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo "\$a[$k] => $v.\n";
}
```

Here $k - will indicate to key of the array.
     $v- will indicate to value of particular key.

To know more please refer following link- 
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php